# Как настроить перенаправление с www на без www в yoast seo?

Tags: wordpress, регулярные-выражения, yoast

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленным плагином [Yoast SEO](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)
Как настроить переадресацию 301 с www на без www через **yoast seo** простое перенаправление или `RegEx`?
(но, не через htaccess | nginx)

Comment: Зачем лишние тормоза на сайт вешать? nginx переадресует примерно в 100 раз быстрее, чем php-код

Comment: @KAGG Design но, тем не менее, если есть такая необходимость - это можно сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ сделать редирект - это сделать его в mu-plugin, до загрузки всех плагинов. Создайте папку `/wp-content/mu-plugins`, если её нет. В ней файл с любым именем и расширением `php`. В файл добавьте такой код:

```
<?php
/**
 * Redirect from www to the same url without www.
 *
 * @package so-ru-1251973
 */

/**
 * Redirect function.
 */
function my_www_redirect() {
    $site_host             = wp_parse_url( site_url(), PHP_URL_HOST );
    $site_host_without_www = preg_replace( '#^www\.#', '', $site_host );
    $site_host_with_www    = 'www.' . $site_host_without_www;

    if (
        (
        isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) ?
            filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
            ''
        ) === $site_host_with_www
    ) {
        require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';

        $request_scheme = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] ) ?
            filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
            'http';
        $request_uri    = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ?
            filter_var( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) :
            '/';

        wp_safe_redirect( $request_scheme . '://' . $site_host_without_www . $request_uri );
    }
}

my_www_redirect();
```